# Duplicate meta descriptions & title tags

Tags: seo, title, meta-description

[image: ****]
    I have website and have some issue with duplicate description and title. Can any body help me to solve this error in easy and simple words?

Comment: You have 4 pages with duplicate description meta-tags and 2 pages with duplicate title tags- this means that these tags are the same across a few pages. In the most ideal case, each page would have a unique title and description. It depends on how your website is built on how to change these. It can be as simple as editing HTML files or updating a post in your CMS or blogging software. You would also need to figure out what pages are the same. We can help you with this, but you will need to tell us more about how your site is made. Editing out the link so that the question does not get closed.

Comment: It looks like you only have 4 pages so there is no problem figuring out which ones should be changed. What are you using to create your site??

Comment: just find the pages which had duplicate titles and descriptions and edit meta Page title and description tags between head head tags manually with your choice of text.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna attempt to go simple as the OP requests.

Each webpage with a title and meta description will contain source code with these lines in it near the beginning of the code:

```
<title>insert title here</title>

<meta name="description" content="insert description here">
```

...Except that "insert title here" is meant to be the actual title and "insert description here" is meant to be the actual description.

What google is telling you is that these two values need to be different for every page on your website. You can't use the same title on two pages nor can you use the same description on two pages.

If by chance you're doing a site involving multiple pages that people can look through, then consider adding "page 1" to the title and "page 1" to the description for the first page of the document, then increment where appropriate.

Here's what I mean. Say I wrote a 3 page article on apples. On page one, I'll have code that includes the following:

```
<title>Apples Page 1</title>

<meta name="description" content="All about Apples. Page number 1">
```

Then on the second page, I would have:

```
<title>Apples Page 2</title>

<meta name="description" content="All about Apples. Page number 2">
```

Then on the third page, I would have:

```
<title>Apples Page 3</title>

<meta name="description" content="All about Apples. Page number 3">
```

Next, if you can change your pages into categories or section names, then that's a bonus since the names are more creative.

Answer (score 1):

The meta-description should be a natural language, brief summary of the page while the meta-keywords should be a concise list of highly relevant keywords in a comma delimited list that are related to concepts, terms or branding elements of the page. Be mindful of your use of trademarked terms in your keywords and branding.

The keywords are NOT a repeat of the description.

Also descriptions and keywords should be specific to the page. Ultimately you want little to no duplication of keywords across pages because you want them seen as unique for the specific topic of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Create UNIQUE title and meta descriptions for each page.

```
<title>Unique Title Here</title>
<meta name="description" content="Unique Meta Description">
```